# Laravel - Ubuntu - Crontab: Should I install cron job for user root?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, cron

I setup my laravel Task Scheduling on my ubuntu server by add this to **root**'s crontab

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

So when the cron job is running, it'll create a log file that belong to user **root**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root        6839 Jan 11 23:00 laravel-2020-01-12.log
```

But the user that run the laravel project is **www-data**, so whenever there's an API call, I got the *Permission denied* error cause **www-data** can not access the log file that belong to **root**.

I try to install contab for **www-data** but I can't access **www-data** user:

```
> su www-data
This account is currently not available.
```

What is the best user to install cronjob for Laravel?

Comment: The best option is to change the owner of that log file to www-data, is there any particular reason that you want the log file's owner is root?

Comment: @catcon, thanks for the response. Actually I don't want the log file's owner is root, I just want to know what is the decent way to do this.
Also I don't think manually changing the owner everyday is a good solution.

Comment: after re-read your question, I want to add something: su www-data command does not work because www-data can not be used to login, instead you can use command `crontab -u www-data -e` to edit www-data's cron jobs. This way the log file's owner will be www-data

Comment: Thanks @catcon, this saved me

Answer (score 0):

[According to Laravel docs...](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#introduction) (using L5.7 as example)

> **Starting The Scheduler**

> When using the scheduler, you only need to add the following Cron
> entry to your server. If you do not know how to add Cron entries to
> your server, consider using a service such as Laravel Forge which can
> manage the Cron entries for you:

`* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

> This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. When
> the schedule:run command is executed, Laravel will evaluate your
> scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

But being in the same boat as you, our log file is being created and owned  by root. The best solution would be to create the cron entries using www-data.

As [@catcon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11430357/catcon) in the comments said, "you can use command `crontab -u www-data -e` to edit www-data's cron jobs"

And adding the crontab entries using `www-data` is how you fix the permission issues.